# Contractability of topological space

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Let X and Y be two topological spaces such that X and X x Y are homotopy equivalent. Does it imply that Y is contractable?

As I am trying, it seems to be true if X and Y are CW complexes, in that Whitehead theorem can do the job. But I am unable to see if spaces are not CW complexes.

Comment: Let $X$ be a noncontractible space, $X^\mathbb{N}$ with the product topology and $X^\mathbb{N}\times X$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: Ok..that’s cool .do you have other interesting example?

Comment: @Max Why not an official answer even it is short?

Comment: @PaulFrost : because I haven't answered the CW-complex part yet

Comment: @Max Same idea: $K(A^\infty, n) \times K(A,n) \simeq K(A^\infty, n)$. The desired result is true if you have some finiteness conditions.

Comment: If the inclusion $X \times * \to X \times Y$ is an equivalence, then $Y$ is weakly contractible (rather tautologically).

Comment: That’s correct. I mean isomorphism induce by a map in case of CW complex.

Comment: That's true in the case of my examples. You need finiteness conditions for this to work. There's not really anything else to say.